# What is the code for showing Custom Category and Subcategory Page?

Tags: custom-post-types

```
hello
We have categories and subcategories like this :
- Category 1
-- SubCategory 1
-- SubCategory 2
-- SubCategory 3
- Category 2
- Category 3
I have one style for all Categories **level 1** and one style for all subcategories **level 2**

I want a code to act like this :

If it was one of Categories level 1 show {
   cat1.php (A page that is fix and show some fix content)
}
else if it was one of SubCategories of level 2 show{
   cat2.php (A page that show only last articles or posts in this subcategory level 2)
}
end;

thanks for your help
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found 2 ways for my problem :

1- you can create a file with name "category.php" for all of your categories and then for every category that you want to add a diffrent style you should create a file like this>> "category-id.php" OR "category-name.php" .

2- another way is that you can do this work by if and else , you should use this code :

```
<?php if (in_category('name')) {
     echo 'htmlcode';
}
elseif (in_category('name-2')) {
     echo 'htmlcode';
}
else {
     echo 'htmlcode';
}
?>
```